# Contact Page not showing correctly in Google Chrome Broswer

Tags: php, xhtml, google-chrome, contacts

I have a one-page portfolio style website that scrolls with JQuery, and I cannot get the "Contact" page to show up fully in the Google Chrome Browser. It works fine in IE, Safari, and Firefox, but not in Chrome. I have attached the code for the "Contact" page to see if someone can see what is wrong. To view the site and see the problem, go to http://www.verticalministries.net/ and navigate to the "Contact" page.

```
<!-- CONTACT section --> 
  <div id="contact">
    <a name="contact"></a>
    <img src="images/contact_txt.png" alt="Contact" title="Contact" class="contact_txt" />
    <div class="contact_info_bg">
        <div class="conact_info">
          <h1>CONTACT VERTICAL</h1>
          <p>We would love to hear from you. Please give us a call or email us using the form to the right with any questions, comments or concerns.</p>
          <p>
            <strong>Phone:</strong> 318-560-4346<br />      
            <strong>Email:</strong> contact@verticalministries.net<br />
            <strong>Waco Hippodrome Address:</strong> 724 Austin Ave. Waco, <abbr title="Texas">TX</abbr><br />
            <strong>Mailing Address:</strong> 1901 S. 14th St., Waco, <abbr title="Texas">TX</abbr> 76706
          </p>
           <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?sourceid=chrome&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=waco+hippodrome&fb=1&gl=us&hq=hippodrome&hnear=waco&cid=0,0,6382554904160266109&ei=0qcxS_3RJcmTnQfGgZWECQ&sa=X&oi=local_result&ct=image&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQnwIwAA" target="_blank"><img src="images/map.gif" alt="Location" title="Location" /></a>
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="contact_form">
        <h1>EMAIL VERTICAL MINISTRIES</h1>
        <form action="#" method="post" id="sendEmail">                      
          <p>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="field" name="nume" />
          </p>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <p>
            <label>E-mail:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="field" name="email" />
          </p>
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <p>
            <label>Message:</label>
            <textarea class="field_textarea" rows="" cols="" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
          </p>                    
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <p>
            <label><?php echo $n1 . ' + ' . $n2; ?> = <br /> <font size="1">security purposes</font></label>          
            <input type="text" id="captcha" class="captcha_field" name="captcha" />
          </p>                    
          <div class="clear"></div>

          <p id="loading"><label>&nbsp;</label><input type="image" id="submit" src="images/send_btn.png" value="Send" /></p>
        </form>  
    </div>
  </div>             
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page runs out of content before it finishes scrolling into view...it scrolls to where the bottom of #content matches the bottom of the page.

You can either add padding in the scrollable object (may affect other browsers), or for a simple yet debate-ably hacky CSS fix:

```
#contact { padding-bottom: 2000px; }
```

This will give it space below that can act as a buffer between the bottom of #content and the bottom of `<html>`

Comment: Thank you Nick. I thought I had tried that but I guess not. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to have `vertical-align:top;` on the #contact div.